# Distributing python-written executable with veusz

Tags: python, py2exe, veusz

I would like to distribute an application written in python as a .exe file. I have already been able to do this using py2exe, but now I have incorporated the veusz library into my code. Ideally my program should open up a veusz plot (as it does on my computer, which has python, numpy, etc. all installed). However, I want to distribute an executable that does this without having to install python.

When I try running my setup.py with py2exe, everything goes fine and the exe is built. However, once the application runs and gets to the point where it is to display the graph, it sends up:

> Runtime error: Unable to find veusz executable on system path.

Can I fix this without having to install a bunch of stuff on my clients' computers? Is this possible? And if I must install something, what is the minimum amount of software I need to install?

Answer (score 1):

Veusz runs its user interface in a separate python process so that it does not block python. If you look at veusz/embed.py, it tries to start up python or a veusz executable. You'd need to modify embed.py to start your .exe (sys.executable) if frozen instead of veusz and pass some special parameter which your program would interpret to start running veusz.embed_remote.runremote.

The python multiprocessing module has to do something similar - you need to call a multiprocess function which checks whether the program was starting by multiprocessing - to get around the fact that Windows doesn't have a working fork.